# Node.js: how to save uploaded file from browser form?

Tags: node.js, file, node.js-stream

What is the best way to save uploaded to node.js files without express?

Answer (score 1):

Express is built around the raw Http module provided by the nodejs core module. Take a look at the docs about [http.createServer](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener)

Because each `req` and `res` in the requestListener is a stream, you can actually do this quite easily with the `fs` core module.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var server = http.createServer(function requestListener (req, res) {
  req.once('end', function onEnd () {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.end('Uploaded File\n');
  });
  req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./uploadedFile.txt'));
});
server.listen(8080);
```

Try uploading the file:

```
# file contains "hello world!"
curl -v -d @test.txt localhost:8080
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:8080/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 12
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 12 out of 12 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 21 Apr 2017 01:34:21 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 14
<
Uploaded File
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

and check out the file

```
 cat uploadedFile.txt
 hello world!
```

Hope this helps!